# Wordpress meta query compare a sum of two keys

Tags: wordpress

I'm implementing a filter for houses and I have two fields in my database: "Bathrooms" and "Toilets". The problem is the next one. When I filter I want my value to be filtered by the sum of those two fields.

For example: I want a house with 2 bathrooms and in my DB I have one with 1 bathroom and 1 Toilet. That one should be included as a result.

Right now, my query only works with bathrooms and not with toilets:

```
if (!empty($_GET['filter_bathrooms'])) {
    $properties['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => '_property_bathrooms',
        'value' => $_GET['filter_bathrooms'],
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'numeric',
    );
}
```

With this code my system will only get those houses with 2 bathrooms and not with 2 (bathrooms+toilets).

My field in the database for toilets is : '_property_toilets'.

Any help?

Comment: I don't think you can easily make this kind of query. What if instead you add a hidden meta (i.e. `bathrooms_sum`) to your custom post, that is updated every time the other two are updated? Then you can make your filter only with that meta_key.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is what you're looking for. You can sort based on different custom meta fields this way.

```
            <?
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
```